# how to copy file from directory to another using shutil in python

Tags: file, copy, pysimplegui

below code always gives me key error of values['-FOUT-'], I need to copy file from one directory to another with different name...values['-FOUT-'] is a key from Pysimplegui to get output directory path, can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? note that if i put a normal string path in quotes it works but I wish to use key path from Pysimplegui , thanks.

shutil.copy2(r'.[PARS] Template Directory\PAR\test.xlsx', os.path.join(str(values['-FOUT-']),"file.xlsx"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code demo the way how to get the new path by user selecting the folder, then you can call `shutil.copy2(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)` to copy the file `src` to the file or directory `dst`.

```py
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg

filename = "file.xlsx"

layout = [
    [sg.Input(disabled=True, enable_events=True, key='-FOUT-'), sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Text(expand_x=True, key='Path')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-FOUT-':
        path = os.path.join(values['-FOUT-'], filename)
        window['Path'].update(f'Path: {repr(path)}')

window.close()
```

[image]